# How to do a range-preserving mapping from LocalDateTime to SQL-DateTime in Slick 3.x?

Tags: mariadb, slick-3.0

I'd like to avoid TIMESTAMP columns in my schema and use DATETIME instead because of the limited range of the former (see [Year 2038 problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem)). Therefore, I defined my column like this

```
def valueDate = column[LocalDateTime]("VALUE_DATE", SqlType("DateTime"))(localDateTimeColumnType)
```

and provided an implicit mapping (I got it somewhere from the web):

```
implicit val localDateTimeColumnType = MappedColumnType.base[LocalDateTime, Timestamp](
  d => Timestamp.from(d.toInstant(ZoneOffset.ofHours(0))),
  d => d.toLocalDateTime
)
```

This works, but by using *java.sql.Timestamp* I still suffer from the limited range, even if my DB column is a DATETIME. I tried to use a String based mapping, but it does not work:

```
implicit val localDateTimeColumnType = MappedColumnType.base[LocalDateTime, String](
  d => d.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS")),
  d => LocalDateTime.parse(d, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS"))
)
```

For some reasons, the insert statement fails (the Futures onFailure callback is called). I wonder how a working range-preserving mapper would look like. Any ideas?

Comment: what it the error message you get in `onFailure` with `String` version?

Comment: I did not know how to capture exceptions in the callback. I looked it up and the message is "Field DayOfYear cannot be printed as the value 157 exceeds the maximum print width of 2". It turned out that my format string was wrong. I'll post an answer to document this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok Lesson #1: Read the error message.

After learning how to display exception messages in play callbacks I got this:

> Field DayOfYear cannot be printed as the value 157 exceeds the maximum print width of 2

It turned out that my DateTime format is rubbish. As one can read [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html), the format has to be *yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss* instead of *YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS*. The correct mapping looks like this:

```
implicit val localDateTimeColumnType = MappedColumnType.base[LocalDateTime, String](
    d => d.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")),
    d => LocalDateTime.parse(d, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))
)
```